# Why does Witten not include higher order quantum corrections when quantizing Poisson brackets in the WZW model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, lie-algebra, affine-lie-algebra, wess-zumino-witten

In ['Non-abelian Bosonization in Two Dimensions'](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103940923), Witten argues that the Poisson brackets of the currents that generate the $G\times G$ symmetry of the WZW model give rise to a Kac-Moody algebra upon canonical quantization.

The Poisson brackets are calculated on page 465 to be
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 \left[X,Y\right]_{PB}&=-\frac{4\pi}{n}\delta(\sigma-\sigma')\textrm{Tr}\bigg([A,B]\frac{\partial g}{\partial\sigma}g^{-1}\bigg)-\frac{4\pi}{n}\delta'(\sigma-\sigma')\textrm{Tr}~AB.
 \end{aligned}\tag{29}
 \end{equation}
for $X=\textrm{Tr} A \frac{\partial g}{\partial \sigma}g^{-1}(\sigma)$ and $Y=\textrm{Tr} B \frac{\partial g}{\partial \sigma'}g^{-1}(\sigma')$, where $g$ is a map $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$, and where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary generators of $G$.

He then states that the relation between Poisson brackets and quantum mechanical commutation relations implies the commutator

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 \left[X,Y\right]_{PB}&=i\hbar\frac{4\pi}{n}\delta(\sigma-\sigma')\textrm{Tr}\bigg([A,B]\frac{\partial g}{\partial\sigma}g^{-1}\bigg)+i\hbar\frac{4\pi}{n}\delta'(\sigma-\sigma')\textrm{Tr}~AB,
 \end{aligned}\tag{30}
 \end{equation}
where I have included Planck's constant explicitly for clarity.

However, it is not clear to me why he does not include terms that are higher order in the Planck constant, which generally occur when going from Poisson brackets to canonical commutators.

One possibility is that dimensional analysis precludes such terms. However, for example, a correction term such as
\begin{equation}
\hbar^2\textrm{Tr}A \frac{\partial g}{\partial \sigma}g^{-1}(\sigma) B \frac{\partial g}{\partial \sigma'}g^{-1}(\sigma')
\end{equation}
does seem consistent with dimensional analysis.

How does one show that there are no $O(\hbar^2)$ terms or higher in the commutator (30)?

Comment: In general, there is latitude in choosing your quantization (ordering) scheme, and those are chosen which [maximally preserve the classical symmetries of the system](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/4/1/383). Crudely, this amounts to picking the prescription which eliminates/minimizes such corrections. The appendix of that link might illustrate the setup.

Comment: It's a definition. The nontrivial claim is that a Hilbert space along with currents satisfying the above commutation relation (without further factors of hbar) actually exists.